Identity in Heyting algebras or not
In some computation over a Heyting algebra, I ended up with the following formula:
$$\Big[(x\to y)\to z\Big]\to \Big[\big(x\to(y\vee z)\big)\vee \big((x\to(y\vee z))\to z\big)\Big]$$
I wonder if it is an identity in Heyting algebras or not, but could not find a derivation nor could I find a counterexample.
However, it's easy to verify that it is an identity in Boolean algebras.
Any ideas?

Coq's tauto tactic fails to find a proof.  Since that tactic is complete for intuitionistic propositional logic, it would seem the answer is "not an identity".

I couldn't help but chuckle at the name of the algebras...

Consider the following Kripke frame:
     1 : x
    /
  0    3 : x, y, z
    \ /
     2
      \
       4 : x, z

Then the only node which satisfies $x \rightarrow y$ is 3, which also satisfies $z$.  Therefore, $0 \Vdash (x \rightarrow y) \rightarrow z$.
On the other hand, node 1 satisfies $x$, but not $y \lor z$; therefore, $0 \not\Vdash x \rightarrow (y \lor z)$.  Also, node 2 satisfies $x \rightarrow (y \lor z)$ but it does not satisfy $z$.  Therefore, $0 \not\Vdash (x \rightarrow (y \lor z)) \rightarrow z$.  We can thus conclude $0 \not\Vdash (x \rightarrow (y \lor z)) \lor ((x \rightarrow (y \lor z)) \rightarrow z)$.
In conclusion, $0 \not\Vdash ((x \rightarrow y) \rightarrow z) \rightarrow [(x \rightarrow (y \lor z)) \lor ((x \rightarrow (y \lor z)) \rightarrow z)]$.

So in terms of a Heyting algebra counterexample, you take the corresponding Heyting algebra of "rightward-closed" subsets of ${ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }$, (i.e. $0 \in S \rightarrow 1 \in S \land 2 \in S$, $2 \in S \rightarrow 3 \in S \land 4 \in S$), and elements $x := { 1, 3, 4 }, y := { 3 }, z := { 3, 4 }$.
